# remove_pointer analog that works for anything that supports operator*

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, sfinae, type-traits

I would like something that has semantics similar to `std::remove_pointer` but works for pointer classes in addition to true pointers. Naturally I could enumerate the known possibilities:

```
// Important: remove_pointer_ex<T>::type should evaluate to T
// if T::operator* is not defined (like std::remove_pointer)
template<typename T> struct remove_pointer_ex { typedef T type; };

template<typename T> struct remove_pointer_ex<T*> { typedef T type; };
template<typename T> struct remove_pointer_ex<std::shared_ptr<T>> { typedef T type; };
template<typename T> struct remove_pointer_ex<std::unique_ptr<T>> { typedef T type; };
// and then again for all the different cv combinations
```

But I'd really like an approach that will work with any class that supports `operator*`.

It seems like this should be doable using SFINAE and/or type traits. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/257288/3549027) describe how to test whether a particular type has a particular member, and I suppose I could use one of those suggestions in combination with `enable_if`, but frankly if there's no less-ugly way to solve the problem, I'd rather just try a completely different approach.

Comment: `remove_reference_t<decltype(*declval<T>())>`?

Comment: Even better: `std::pointer_traits<T>::element_type`.

Comment: @MarcGlisse The unfortunate problem with those is that, unlike `remove_pointer` they don't compile when `T` is not a pointer type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a type trait that defaults to `T` but prefers `std::remove_reference<decltype(*T)>` when it is valid ([Live at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70aa780ac76b17d5)):

```
template <typename T>
class remove_pointer_ {
    template <typename U=T>
    static auto test(int) -> std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::declval<U>())>;
    static auto test(...) -> std::remove_cv<T>;

public:
    using type = typename decltype(test(0))::type;
};

template <typename T>
using remove_pointer = typename remove_pointer_<T>::type;
```

Comment: This doesn't work for pointers to arrays or functions. But this is easily worked around with a wrapper type: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81e7754e3a5e4529

Comment: That looks like it will do it. I had to make a couple adjustments before Microsoft's partial C++11 support would accept it (they don't like the usings or having a default template argument on a function), and it doesn't drop cv qualifiers like `std::remove_pointer` does, but that isn't difficult to add.

Comment: @Brian Thanks - incorporated into the answer, with arbitrary style changes since [I prefer the bikeshed to be blue](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding).